# Am I being hacked??? And what to do to get out of it?

Tags: mysql, security, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

One fine morning I discovered that I no longer can ssh mysql server on my AWS ubuntu 18.04 instance.
To cut the story short, I completely removed and then  reinstalled mysql. But I am still unable to start mysql.
Error message include the line "See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."
Here is systemctl status mysql.service response:

```
ubuntu@ip-1xx-30-x-2xx:/$ systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-08-28 12:41:02 UTC; 2min 5s ago
  Process: 5067 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exite
  Process: 5045 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS    
Aug 28 12:41:01 ip-xxx-30-0-xxx systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 28 12:41:01 ip-xxx-30-0-xxx systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Aug 28 12:41:02 ip-xxx-30-0-xxx systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling re
Aug 28 12:41:02 ip-xxx-30-0-xxx systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is
Aug 28 12:41:02 ip-xxx-30-0-xxx systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Aug 28 12:41:02 ip-xxx-30-0-xxx systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 28 12:41:02 ip-xxx-30-0-xxx systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 28 12:41:02 ip-xxx-30-0-xxx systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

And here is journalctl -xe response:

```
ubuntu@ip-1xx-30-x-2xx:/$ journalctl -xe
    Aug 28 12:43:59 ip-xxx-30-0-xxx sshd[5180]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for root from 58.218.92.43 port 14
    Aug 28 12:43:59 ip-xxx-30-0-xxx sshd[5180]: Disconnecting authenticating user root 58.218.92.43 port 14426: Too many authentic
    Aug 28 12:43:59 ip-xxx-30-0-xxx sshd[5180]: PAM 5 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=58.
    Aug 28 12:43:59 ip-xxx-30-0-xxx sshd[5180]: PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
    Aug 28 12:44:05 ip-xxx-30-0-xxx sshd[5197]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser=
    Aug 28 12:44:07 ip-xxx-30-0-xxx sshd[5197]: Failed password for root from 58.218.92.43 port 10186 ssh2
    Aug 28 12:44:10 ip-xxx-30-0-xxx sshd[5197]: Failed password for root from 58.218.92.43 port 10186 ssh2

    .
    .
```

. and this repeated over and over. I dont know anything about IP 58.218.92.43;

The question is am I being hacked? and what to do to get out of it?

Comment: Try to use `tcpdump` and see if it uses random password to try to connect your database, if so change another port or just open your firewall.

Comment: Might this get a better answer at https://security.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: the IP address tracks back to `CHINANET jiangsu province network`

Comment: It's recommended to use a VPN so only you have direct access to your AWS instances. Otherwise your instances are exposed to anyone on the internet to attempt brute-force hacking attempts like the one you saw evidence of. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpn-connections.html